# Page redirects to same page after form submit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I used "Leave a Comment" form in my blog page template.
And all the comments displaying there only.
After submitting the comment, it is redirecting to original page(Single.php).

How can i do redirects the current page after submitting the comment?
Here is my code.

```
<div class="blogcontactcontenttwo">     
<h4><?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Reply', 'Leave a Reply to %s' ); ?></h4>
<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
<p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
<?php else : ?> 
    <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>
    <p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>
<?php else : ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="author">Name * <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="email">Email * <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <label>Comments *</label>                   
            <p><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="74%" rows="5" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="submetblog">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Post Comment" />
<?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
<?php echo the_permalink() ?>
</div> 
    </form>
    <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
    <?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
</div>
```

[image]